# Laplace transform polynomial fraction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Can anybody help, how do I find the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{s^3 + 3s^2 + 2s + 4}$?

Comment: You would want to use partial fractions, but the denominator here does not admit an easy factorization.

Comment: Indeed; in Mathematica, $\texttt{Apart[]}$ does not even attempt to find the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: @Math1000. You can try:`sol = Solve[4 + 2 s + 3 s^2 + s^3 == 0, s] // ToRadicals // 
  Simplify; 1/((s - (s /. sol[[1]]))*(s - (s /. sol[[2]]))*(s - (s /. 
      sol[[3]]))) // TraditionalForm`

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, the factorization is not easy, in particular because the equation shows two non(real complex conjugate roots.

Assuming that you know how to work with the reciprocal of a quadratic polynomial, we can write
$$s^3 + 3s^2 + 2s + 4=(s+1+k) \Big(s^2+(2-k) s+\frac 4{1+k}\Big)$$
where
$$k=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{3}}\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(6
   \sqrt{3}\right)\right)$$
and the partial fraction decomposition woudl give
$$\frac{1}{s^3 + 3s^2 + 2s + 4}=\frac{1}{2 k^3+3 k^2+3}\Big( \frac{k+1}{s+k+1}+\frac{\left(2 k^3+3 k^2-1\right)-(k+1)^2 s } {4+\left(-k^2+k+2\right) s+(k+1) s^2 }    \Big)$$